# Select all duplicate rows except for one record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I need to select the duplicate records in this table except one.

#### Example Data

```
+-------+-------+------+
| nid   | vid   | uid  |
+-------+-------+-------
| 701   |   209 |   11 |
| 701   |   210 |   11 |
| 701   |   211 |   11 |
| 701   |   212 |   1  |
| 701   |   213 |   1  |
| 701   |   214 |   97 |
| 701   |   215 |   97 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

#### Expected Results

I need to get this result with where condition for nid such as 701.

```
+-------+-------+------+
| nid   | vid   | uid  |
+-------+-------+-------
| 701   |   210 |   11 |
| 701   |   211 |   11 |
| 701   |   213 |   1  |
| 701   |   215 |   97 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

Any help would be appreaciated

Comment: Specify MySQL version (5 or 8?).\

Comment: @Akina - It's version 5.7

Comment: If some `uid` has 4 duplicates - does you need 3 output records with this `uid`? Is `vid` unique over table, over `nid`, or no such restrictions?

Comment: Define duplicate -- Every row in your sample is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the subquery you select the rows you want to keep. With the outer query you select all rows that are not in your subquery.

```
SELECT 
t.*
FROM
t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    MIN(nid) AS nid, MIN(vid) AS vid, uid
    FROM t
    GROUP BY uid
) t2 USING(nid, vid, uid)
WHERE t2.uid IS NULL;
```

Note that this would also not display rows where there are no duplicates. To display them as well you just don't select them in the subquery:

```
SELECT 
t.*
FROM
t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    MIN(nid) AS nid, MIN(vid) AS vid, uid
    FROM t
    GROUP BY uid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2 USING(nid, vid, uid)
WHERE t2.uid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Both of them returns all resultset :(

Comment: Not for me. See it working live in an sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45db63/3/0

Comment: @RajeevK Also works with your sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34dbe/2/0

Comment: I have tried replicating with a sample data I am working here, but that doesn't return the same like yours

Comment: If I need to add condition for "nid" such as 701, where can I put that? Adding that in end of statement after IS NULL not giving proper result

Comment: After IS NULL should work, as long as you choose `t.nid`, not `t2.nid`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99734/discussion-between-rajeevk-and-tombom).

Comment: @Akina That's not wrong, it's like I described it in the text above it. When you don't want to display them, use the first query.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: I guess my english could be less confusing :)

Comment: Not sure why, but when I try with with sqlfiddle, adding t.nid=701 works, but if I try the same in my local mysql, it returns all resultset. It's frustrating, so now I have sorted this at program level... Thanks @tombom

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM sourcetable t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM sourcetable t2
               WHERE (t1.nid, t1.uid) = (t2.nid, t2.uid)
                 AND t1.vid > t2.vid )
```

Logic: return records for which there is at least one record with the same `nid` and `uid` and lower `vid`. So the record with the least `vid` will be skipped.